# Getting 'Page not found' when trying to post a comment using the Busy theme

Tags: 7, comments

I'm having a heck of time trying to get comments to post to my nodes. I've done all the obvious:

Enable comment module, set appropriate permissions, etc.

But every time I try to enter a comment it simply redirects to a "Add new comment" page and nothing gets posted. There is no comment in the Content -> Comments section and my database comment table is empty.

The only thing I can find relating to the issue is an error report in my log messages which displays a warning "page not found." I'm using the Drupal [Busy theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/busy).

```
Type: Page not found
Location: http://mysite/public://color/busy-0970ccd8/style.css?m
Message: public://color/busy-0970ccd8/style.css
Severity: Warning
```

I've ran the schema module and nothing is funky in with my database. Any thoughts on this? Much appreciated.

Comment: Try switching to the Bartik theme and see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: Patrick, I just switched over to Bartik for a comment test and still nothing, nada, zilch. Nothing in my Content -> Comments section, or in the comment table in the database.